# Accessing a socket from another activity

Tags: android

I want to create a socket object and I want to access it from another activity, how can I save this object(socket) and be able to get it through different activities.

In one activity,I am sending and receiving data from a server, and I want to use it in another acivity

Comment: That may be a poor idea, but Binder IPC supports passing live file descriptors.  For another Activity in the same Application (and thus perhaps same process), a global may be an option with extreme care in managing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one option would be to make a class and include a static socket object , initialize this socket and use this static socket object anywhere in your application

Comment: what do you mean by "include static object" and can I include it in the activities which are using the socket?

Comment: in a class make a static object of socket, you can also provide static methods to send, receive, data to and from socket, where you want to use socket functionality , just use class methods. ALGO: `class mySocket{ private static socket mysocket; public static initializeSocket() {// add initialization code here e.g ip address ,port etc} public static sendData(byte[] data{//send data via socket} }`